# Create custom json_encode function

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$word = Array(
    'dictionaries' => Array(
        'posDict' => Array(),
        'wordPosDict' => Array(
            '1' => Array(1, 4, 5)
        )
    )
);
```

which when encoded to json has to have the following format:

```
"{"dictionaries":{"posDict":{},"wordPosDict":{"1":[1,4,5]}}}"
```

`posDict` has to be an object and the key `1` in `wordPosDict` has to be an array. Currently, I can't do that with json_encode:

```
json_encode($word)
```

gives

```
"{"dictionaries":{"posDict":[],"wordPosDict":{"1":[1,4,5]}}}"
```

`posDict` is array

```
json_encode($word, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

gives

```
"{"dictionaries":{"posDict":{},"wordPosDict":{"1":{"0":1,"1":4,"2":5}}}}"
```

everything is object, but the key `1` in `wordPosDict` has to be an array.

My question is what is the best way to achieve the result I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still use `json_encode` to process conversion from PHP to JSON. You can transform your PHP object before calling `json_encode`.

Instead of assigning `array()` to `"posDict"` key, try assigning `new stdClass()`.